# Not sure which MySQL data type to use

Tags: mysql, database

In general, I have double values that I work with. I use them as double values and also as strings (in application code). I store them as Double in my MySQL database.

The problem I have is with trailing 0's. For example, the value I get is 10.60. This value gets truncated down to 10.6 which is not ok for me. I need that trailing 0.

I also need it to not add 0's. For example, if I got 10.60, it should not add 0's to be 10.600. I am not sure which data type fits my needs. It needs to be stored as the double value, but keep its trailing 0's, and not add any additional 0's.

Can anyone assist me in which data type to use?

Comment: Is there a reason other than display requirements to have the trailing zeros conditionally displayed? Also, do you need to do any manipulation/sorting/querying/etc. based on these values?

Comment: The only reason I need the trailing 0's is for display purposes. They come in via OCR and so need to be in the output. There are calculations that are preformed, but they are all in application code. Nothing done in the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the double values in a double/real field only and not varchar so as to not lose any precision during conversion. Since the issue is only in application code, I would  round them to the appropriate decimal places (using the [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function) while retrieving from the database.

Comment: I don't believe my database knowledge is that great. Could you please show me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an example for using ROUND function on a database column during retrieval?